# Wix - previous product which is a feature in a future product

Tags: wix, installation, release, product, uninstallation

In the past, we have released a product called A. We are about to release a new product B, which contains A as a module (coded as a Wix feature). So we have now the "product A" (the previous product) and the "module A" (feature of B).

Then we have the following bug : uninstallation of product A doesn't remove installation of feature A, and vice versa.

We can make the installer of product B to uninstall A when the installer of B is launched (for example by a custom action), but I fear we will have to release a new version of product A that does the same thing.

Is there any better solution, not involving releasing a new version of product A ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, Product A has been installed and now Product B has been released which contains everything that was in Product A.

You don't need a custom action - you can arrange a major upgrade that will uninstall product A when product B is installed. If Product B always replaces Product A, then they can have the same upgrade code, and you can just let Windows replace Product A with Product B via major upgrade.

The feature A thing is normal. If you install Product A and then Install Product B, the components in feature A are shared between Products A and B. When you uninstall Product A the product is removed but the components are shared and the feature A that remains belongs to Product B. This is normal. Note that features are not shared between products, only components. Feature A is not shared - there is a feature A in both product A and B that share components, that's all. It would be wrong if you uninstalled Product A and it removed feature A from Product B. There is not a single feature A on the system - features are owned only by products.

Comment: The last sentence is confusing. Do you mean to say that each feature is owned by exactly one project: Feature A of Product A is distinct from Feature A of Product B (even if they reference the same set of components)?

Comment: The upgrade code thing worked, thanks ! Also thank you for the explanation in the last paragraph.

Comment: Tom: a feature in an MSI file is just a mapping to a collection of components. Yes, feature A in product A is a mapping to a set of components that happens to be the same mapping as in product B.